# jQuery - Search on text entry - delay until full term entered

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which detects any text entered into the `#search-box` field and then immediately runs the search (if greater than 2 characters):

```
$('#search-box').on('input', function() { 

    var term = $(this).val();
    if (term.length > 2) {
      //execute search and display results
    }

});
```

This doesn't look pretty though, as if you were to type `dollar` for example, after 'doll' a load of dolls will appear, which will then be replaced with dollars once `dolla` is entered. This can happen in a split second.

What I'd like to do is determine whether the user has finished the search term. Is it possible to wait for a second or 2 before doing the search? And if in that waiting period the user enters another letter, it resets the clock?

Comment: So basically you need if user type dolla and he want to type dollar so we will skip all the request and final request will be the dollar. As he finish typing the dollar then search request will run..?

Comment: Yes! Ideally if the user stops typing for 2 seconds, run the request.  Otherwise skip the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `setTimeout()` for waiting after input.

```
var tim = '';
$('#search-box').on('input', function() { 
    clearTimeout(tim);
    tim = setTimeout(my_func, 2000); //2000 means 2 seconds; 
});

function my_func() {
    var term = $(this).val();
    if (term.length > 2) {
        //execute search and display results
    }
}
```

Seconds are in `ms` and hence you can also set something like `1500` for one and half second.

`clearTimeout` is used for destroying values in `tim`. After `clearTimeout(tim)`, `tim` becomes zero and then starts after increase/decrease in length of `#search-box`.

Comment: If the user types "dollar", would this code run 4 times, just with a 2 second delay? Or would it be interrupted 3 times and just run the once?

Comment: You want to detect if the input contains `dollar` symbol in the string and run your custom functions each time?

Comment: Sorry I picked a poor word.  Imagine I type "HELLO".  The code would run 3 times: "HEL", "HELL" and "HELLO".  I want to avoid this, and only run if there has been a wait of 2 seconds.  If the time is less than this between keystrokes, then reset the clock.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, please check my updated answer! Its exactly how you need it to be!

Comment: Perfect thanks! I had to change `var term = $(this).val();` to `var term = $('#search-box').val();`